# scp not working well in 100mbps LAN

Tags: linux, networking, scp, code-blocks

I have a compile environment that scps files to a target machine after they have been built over the LAN. Initially this was working well but after several builds, deploys, and reboots, it has become unbearably slow taking upwards of 30+ minutes to compile and deploy a project. It used to take only a couple minutes!

It's not just abysmally slow speeds (~100kbps) that are the issue but then after it finishes transferring the file it hangs for an additional 2-3+ seconds which it did not do before.

What can be causing this? Anything I can do to clear/reset what might have changed?

Comment: You can use `scp -vv` to get lots of debug output that may help you to determine where the bottlenecks are, possibly.  Also, if you do a lot of making and breaking `ssh` connections over this process, you might think about setting up a Master connection and connection muxing in your `.ssh/config`.

Comment: How's the target disk?  What kind of files are we talking about?  If you have lots of small files and/or high fragmentation, you could be running into disk based issues . . .

Comment: For me it was removing wireless from the equation. The tranceiver in an old wireless router, which couldn't talk through the walls as well as it did when new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was due to overloaded switches (16 used ports across 3 6 port switches). Upgraded to a 24 port one and scp now returns immediately and reaches higher speeds.